# How to efficiently find maximum of selected indices of an array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Let us say we have the vectors: `w`, `s_on`, and `s_off`. s_on and s_off have the ascending indices of the onset and offset of an event. We need to find the maximum value in during each event. How can we do it without using loop.
for example we may have the following values:

```
s_on = [5 19 78 101];
s_off = [10 28 97 152];
w = rand(1,200);
```

The following code does not work:

```
pv = max(w(s_on(1:end):s_off(1:end)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the data be defined as

```
s_on = [5 19 78 101];
s_off = [10 28 97 152];
w = rand(1,200);
```

The maximum for each range of indices can be computed as follows:

```
[v, t] = max(bsxfun(@ge, 1:numel(w), s_on(:)) & bsxfun(@le, 1:numel(w), s_off(:)), [], 1);
result = accumarray(t(v).', w(v).', [], @max);
```

A loop would be more readable:

```
result_loop = NaN(numel(s_on), 1);
for k = 1:numel(s_on)
    result_loop(k) = max(w(s_on(k):s_off(k)));
end
```

Check that both approaches give the same result:

```
isequal(result, result_loop)
```